# COUNT causes error in db2 from PHP

Tags: php, db2

When I run this query I get the following error:

```
Column MANUFACTURER or expression in SELECT list not valid.
```

The query runs fine if I remove the COUNT function.

Any ideas?

(this query is a bit of a mock so it might not make perfect sense)

```
SELECT
  MANUFACTURER
, PART_NUMBER
, COUNT(1) AS CNT
FROM 
( SELECT
    AWPART AS PART_NUMBER  
  , MANF AS MANUFACTURER       
  FROM STKMP                        
    INNER JOIN PRICING AS P         
      ON AWPART = P.JCPART  
      AND R.CODE = 1        
    WHERE  PART_NUMBER LIKE '%A2%') AS T
```

Modifying the last line as follows produces the same effect.

```
WHERE  PART_NUMBER LIKE '%A2%') AS T  GROUP BY MANUFACTURER
```

Comment: I just have some comments, because it does look like a strange query. Do you just need to drop the 'AS T', or both add 'TABLE' just after FROM, and add 'T.' as a prefix to each of MANUFACTURER and PART_NUMBER in the select list? I don't have access to DB2 to test, but these are my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `COUNT()` is only meaningful if you have a `GROUP BY` clause. Perhaps you meant to add this to the end (after the `AS T`?):

```
GROUP BY MANUFACTURER, PART_NUMBER;
```